# How dynamicly change property of object by template string

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

In my angualar project I have a table with a list of users and the search bar. Here is my search function:

```
searchUser() {
    const regExp = new RegExp(this.searchTerm, 'gi');

    this.users = this.users.filter((user) => regExp.test(user.username));
}
```

Now its searching only by username, but I want to be able to search by selected field. I have a select with options of my search criterion. So I dont know how dynamicly change property of user object inside filter fuction in according to selected search criterion.

I've thought about es6 template strings and tried like this:

```
this.users = this.users.filter((user) => regExp.test(user`.${this.selectedCriterion}`)
```

But it didn't work. What is the proper syntax for this?
Will appreciate any advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use computed property syntax,

```
this.users = this.users.filter((user) => regExp.test(user[this.selectedCriterion])
```

Comment: Thanks) It works